# calling npm run lint from bitbucket pipeline resulting error

Tags: bitbucket, eslint, pipeline, lint, bitbucket-pipelines

i have a problem with this bitbucket pipeline i wrote any help will be much appreciated!

so this is how my bitbucket pipeline yml file looks like:

```
definitions:
  caches:
   npm: ~/.npm



pipelines:
  branches:
    master:
    - step:
        name: Package Install
        caches:
          - npm
        script:
          - npm install
    - step:
        name: build
        caches:
          - npm
        script:
          - npm run build
    - step:
        name: lint
        caches:
          - npm
        script:
          - npm install
          - npm run lint
```

when i run the pipeline it logs the following:

```
+ npm run lint
> pipelines@1.0.0 lint /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build
> eslint '**/*.js' --fix/;exit 0
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js:93
        } catch {
                ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:607:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:684:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
```

but when i run "npm run lint" from my shell i get a valid output as follows:

```
> pipelines@1.0.0 lint /Users/giladshemtov/pipelines
> eslint '**/*.js' --fix/;exit 0

Warning: React version not specified in eslint-plugin-react settings. See https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react#configuration .

/Users/giladshemtov/pipelines/.eslintrc.js
  1:1  error  'module' is not defined  no-undef

/Users/giladshemtov/pipelines/App.js
    9:31  error  'useRoute' is defined but never used                     no-unused-vars
   39:13  error  'require' is not defined                                 no-undef
   40:20  error  'require' is not defined                                 no-undef
   41:17  error  'require' is not defined                                 no-undef
   42:23  error  'require' is not defined                                 no-undef
   43:19  error  'require' is not defined                                 no-undef
   44:18  error  'require' is not defined                                 no-undef
   45:24  error  'require' is not defined                                 no-undef
   46:20  error  'require' is not defined                                 no-undef
   47:22  error  'require' is not defined                                 no-undef
   55:18  error  'navigation' is missing in props validation              react/prop-types
   55:29  error  'navigation.canGoBack' is missing in props validation    react/prop-types
   55:83  error  'navigation' is missing in props validation              react/prop-types
   55:94  error  'navigation.goBack' is missing in props validation       react/prop-types
   63:50  error  'navigation' is missing in props validation              react/prop-types
   63:61  error  'navigation.navigate' is missing in props validation     react/prop-types
   68:34  error  'navigation' is missing in props validation              react/prop-types
   68:45  error  'navigation.openDrawer' is missing in props validation   react/prop-types
  100:11  error  'navigation' is missing in props validation              react/prop-types
  100:22  error  'navigation.closeDrawer' is missing in props validation  react/prop-types
  105:32  error  'require' is not defined                                 no-undef
  128:25  error  'navigation' is missing in props validation              react/prop-types
  128:36  error  'navigation.navigate' is missing in props validation     react/prop-types

/Users/giladshemtov/pipelines/babel.config.js
  1:1  error  'module' is not defined  no-undef

/Users/giladshemtov/pipelines/src/components/Button.js
   9:5  error  'onPress' is missing in props validation    react/prop-types
  10:5  error  'text' is missing in props validation       react/prop-types
  11:5  error  'style' is missing in props validation      react/prop-types
  12:5  error  'textStyle' is missing in props validation  react/prop-types
  13:5  error  'textType' is missing in props validation   react/prop-types
  14:5  error  'children' is missing in props validation   react/prop-types

/Users/giladshemtov/pipelines/src/components/Counter.js
   9:5  error  'onInc' is missing in props validation    react/prop-types
  10:5  error  'onDec' is missing in props validation    react/prop-types
  11:5  error  'min' is missing in props validation      react/prop-types
  12:5  error  'initial' is missing in props validation  react/prop-types
  13:5  error  'size' is missing in props validation     react/prop-types

/Users/giladshemtov/pipelines/src/components/Flow.js
   8:20  error  'done' is missing in props validation         react/prop-types
   8:26  error  'icon' is missing in props validation         react/prop-types
  28:10  error  Component definition is missing display name  react/display-name
  28:12  error  'done' is missing in props validation         react/prop-types
  28:18  error  'size' is missing in props validation         react/prop-types
  29:10  error  Component definition is missing display name  react/display-name
  29:12  error  'done' is missing in props validation         react/prop-types
  29:18  error  'size' is missing in props validation         react/prop-types
  30:10  error  Component definition is missing display name  react/display-name
  30:12  error  'done' is missing in props validation         react/prop-types
  30:18  error  'size' is missing in props validation         react/prop-types
  33:31  error  'current' is missing in props validation      react/prop-types

/Users/giladshemtov/pipelines/src/components/Footer.js
  2:10  error  'Footer' is defined but never used        no-unused-vars
  2:18  error  'FooterTab' is defined but never used     no-unused-vars
  2:35  error  'Item' is defined but never used          no-unused-vars
  8:20  error  'btnTxt' is missing in props validation   react/prop-types
  8:28  error  'onPress' is missing in props validation  react/prop-types
  8:37  error  'text1' is missing in props validation    react/prop-types
  8:44  error  'text2' is missing in props validation    react/prop-types

/Users/giladshemtov/pipelines/src/components/Header.js
  2:34  error  'StyleSheet' is defined but never used      no-unused-vars
  3:7   error  'isIos' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars
  8:12  error  'children' is missing in props validation   react/prop-types

/Users/giladshemtov/pipelines/src/components/ProductCard.js
  19:24  error  'img' is missing in props validation               react/prop-types
  19:29  error  'price' is missing in props validation             react/prop-types
  19:36  error  'desc' is missing in props validation              react/prop-types
  19:42  error  'manufacturer' is missing in props validation      react/prop-types
  19:56  error  'name' is missing in props validation              react/prop-types
  19:62  error  'onAddPressed' is missing in props validation      react/prop-types
  19:76  error  'onDetailsPressed' is missing in props validation  react/prop-types

/Users/giladshemtov/pipelines/src/components/SearchBar.js
   2:27  error  'Button' is defined but never used                  no-unused-vars
   2:45  error  'DatePickerIOSComponent' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
   3:10  error  'Item' is defined but never used                    no-unused-vars
   3:29  error  'ListItem' is defined but never used                no-unused-vars
   3:45  error  'List' is defined but never used                    no-unused-vars
   3:51  error  'Body' is defined but never used                    no-unused-vars
   5:7   error  'isIos' is assigned a value but never used          no-unused-vars
  21:30  error  'data' is not defined                               no-undef
  36:23  error  'replace' is missing in props validation            react/prop-types
  53:22  error  'onSearch' is missing in props validation           react/prop-types
  53:32  error  'onChangeText' is missing in props validation       react/prop-types
  53:46  error  'onItemPress' is missing in props validation        react/prop-types
  53:59  error  'handleSubmit' is missing in props validation       react/prop-types
  53:59  error  'handleSubmit' is defined but never used            no-unused-vars
  53:73  error  'getSuggestions' is missing in props validation     react/prop-types
  59:5   error  'onSearch' is assigned a value but never used       no-unused-vars

/Users/giladshemtov/pipelines/src/components/Text.js
  2:10  error  'View' is defined but never used           no-unused-vars
  2:22  error  'StyleProp' is defined but never used      no-unused-vars
  2:33  error  'TextStyle' is defined but never used      no-unused-vars
  9:24  error  'style' is missing in props validation     react/prop-types
  9:31  error  'type' is missing in props validation      react/prop-types
  9:37  error  'children' is missing in props validation  react/prop-types

/Users/giladshemtov/pipelines/src/screens/Cart.js
  10:8   error  'Footer' is defined but never used                              no-unused-vars
  16:37  error  'navigation' is missing in props validation                     react/prop-types
  32:58  error  'navigation.navigate' is missing in props validation            react/prop-types
  40:17  error  'item' is missing in props validation                           react/prop-types
  46:73  error  'item.product' is missing in props validation                   react/prop-types
  46:81  error  'item.product.name' is missing in props validation              react/prop-types
  47:11  error  'item.product' is missing in props validation                   react/prop-types
  47:19  error  'item.product.manufacturerName' is missing in props validation  react/prop-types
  48:50  error  'item.product' is missing in props validation                   react/prop-types
  48:58  error  'item.product.manufacturerName' is missing in props validation  react/prop-types
  52:25  error  'item.product' is missing in props validation                   react/prop-types
  52:33  error  'item.product.image' is missing in props validation             react/prop-types
  60:54  error  'item.product' is missing in props validation                   react/prop-types
  60:62  error  'item.product.default_price' is missing in props validation     react/prop-types
  61:77  error  'item.product' is missing in props validation                   react/prop-types
  72:57  error  'item.product' is missing in props validation                   react/prop-types
  73:57  error  'item.product' is missing in props validation                   react/prop-types
  74:20  error  'item.quantity' is missing in props validation                  react/prop-types

/Users/giladshemtov/pipelines/src/screens/Categories.js
   1:17  error  'Component' is defined but never used            no-unused-vars
   2:21  error  'Content' is defined but never used              no-unused-vars
   2:30  error  'Icon' is defined but never used                 no-unused-vars
   2:35  error  'Item' is defined but never used                 no-unused-vars
   2:40  error  'Text' is defined but never used                 no-unused-vars
   2:46  error  'Left' is defined but never used                 no-unused-vars
   2:52  error  'Right' is defined but never used                no-unused-vars
  48:24  error  'category' is missing in props validation        react/prop-types
  52:94  error  'category.name' is missing in props validation   react/prop-types
  65:30  error  'category.image' is missing in props validation  react/prop-types
  70:57  error  'category.name' is missing in props validation   react/prop-types

/Users/giladshemtov/pipelines/src/screens/Failure.js
   7:10  error  'widthPercentage' is defined but never used           no-unused-vars
  15:34  error  'navigation' is missing in props validation           react/prop-types
  15:46  error  'route' is missing in props validation                react/prop-types
  20:14  error  'navigation.navigate' is missing in props validation  react/prop-types
  24:14  error  'navigation.goBack' is missing in props validation    react/prop-types
  38:58  error  'route.params' is missing in props validation         react/prop-types
  38:65  error  'route.params.error' is missing in props validation   react/prop-types

/Users/giladshemtov/pipelines/src/screens/FlowCommon.js
  24:26   error  'valid' is missing in props validation           react/prop-types
  24:40   error  'onChangeText' is missing in props validation    react/prop-types
  24:54   error  'style' is missing in props validation           react/prop-types
  24:61   error  'children' is missing in props validation        react/prop-types
  24:71   error  'placeholder' is missing in props validation     react/prop-types
  24:84   error  'textInputStyle' is missing in props validation  react/prop-types
  24:100  error  'textInputProps' is missing in props validation  react/prop-types
  55:24   error  'children' is missing in props validation        react/prop-types
  55:34   error  'style' is missing in props validation           react/prop-types
  69:28   error  'onPress' is missing in props validation         react/prop-types

/Users/giladshemtov/pipelines/src/screens/Payment.js
  16:9   error  'route' is missing in props validation                              react/prop-types
  18:4   error  'route.params.address' is missing in props validation               react/prop-types
  19:5   error  'route.params.phone' is missing in props validation                 react/prop-types
  20:5   error  'route.params.description' is missing in props validation           react/prop-types
  21:5   error  'route.params.selectedDeliveryMode' is missing in props validation  react/prop-types
  22:12  error  'route.params' is missing in props validation                       react/prop-types
  48:26  error  '_' is defined but never used                                       no-unused-vars
  49:17  error  '_' is defined but never used                                       no-unused-vars
  49:20  error  '__' is defined but never used                                      no-unused-vars
  50:4   error  Mixed spaces and tabs                                               no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs
  50:17  error  '_' is defined but never used                                       no-unused-vars
  77:12  error  'navigation' is missing in props validation                         react/prop-types
  77:23  error  'navigation.dispatch' is missing in props validation                react/prop-types
  97:12  error  'navigation' is missing in props validation                         react/prop-types
  97:23  error  'navigation.navigate' is missing in props validation                react/prop-types

/Users/giladshemtov/pipelines/src/screens/Product.js
   15:35  error  'route' is missing in props validation                                  react/prop-types
   15:42  error  'navigation' is missing in props validation                             react/prop-types
   17:25  error  'route.params' is missing in props validation                           react/prop-types
   17:32  error  'route.params.product' is missing in props validation                   react/prop-types
   39:33  error  'route.params.product.default_price' is missing in props validation     react/prop-types
   40:27  error  'route.params.product.name' is missing in props validation              react/prop-types
   41:27  error  'route.params.product.description' is missing in props validation       react/prop-types
   41:51  error  'route.params.product.name' is missing in props validation              react/prop-types
   41:66  error  'route.params.product.description' is missing in props validation       react/prop-types
   42:33  error  'route.params.product.image' is missing in props validation             react/prop-types
   43:35  error  'route.params.product.manufacturerName' is missing in props validation  react/prop-types
   50:37  error  'navigation.goBack' is missing in props validation                      react/prop-types
   63:32  error  'product' is missing in props validation                                react/prop-types
   63:41  error  'visible' is missing in props validation                                react/prop-types
   63:50  error  'onClose' is missing in props validation                                react/prop-types
   76:86  error  'product.name' is missing in props validation                           react/prop-types
   77:83  error  'product.default_price' is missing in props validation                  react/prop-types
   88:24  error  'product.manufacturerName' is missing in props validation               react/prop-types
   88:79  error  'product.manufacturerName' is missing in props validation               react/prop-types
   90:25  error  'product.specification' is missing in props validation                  react/prop-types
   90:40  error  'product.specification.map' is missing in props validation              react/prop-types
   97:43  error  'product.image' is missing in props validation                          react/prop-types
  105:7   error  'styles' is assigned a value but never used                             no-unused-vars

/Users/giladshemtov/pipelines/src/screens/Products.js
   17:41  error  'route' is missing in props validation                     react/prop-types
   24:11  error  'route.params.getProducts' is missing in props validation  react/prop-types
   24:33  error  'route.params' is missing in props validation              react/prop-types
   52:13  error  'route.params' is missing in props validation              react/prop-types
   52:20  error  'route.params.getProducts' is missing in props validation  react/prop-types
   83:20  error  'product' is missing in props validation                   react/prop-types
   99:29  error  'product.image' is missing in props validation             react/prop-types
  103:63  error  'product.name' is missing in props validation              react/prop-types
  104:14  error  'product.manufacturerName' is missing in props validation  react/prop-types
  104:92  error  'product.manufacturerName' is missing in props validation  react/prop-types
  107:58  error  'product.default_price' is missing in props validation     react/prop-types

/Users/giladshemtov/pipelines/src/screens/PurchaseFlowAddress.js
   2:26  error  'StyleSheet' is defined but never used                no-unused-vars
   2:56  error  'TextInput' is defined but never used                 no-unused-vars
   4:8   error  'Footer' is defined but never used                    no-unused-vars
   7:18  error  'Fonts' is defined but never used                     no-unused-vars
  12:10  error  'AntDesign' is defined but never used                 no-unused-vars
  21:47  error  'navigation' is missing in props validation           react/prop-types
  42:16  error  '_' is defined but never used                         no-unused-vars
  44:15  error  'navigation.navigate' is missing in props validation  react/prop-types

/Users/giladshemtov/pipelines/src/screens/Success.js
   2:28  error  'Image' is defined but never used                                       no-unused-vars
   7:27  error  'heightPercentage' is defined but never used                            no-unused-vars
   8:18  error  'fontSize' is defined but never used                                    no-unused-vars
  14:34  error  'navigation' is missing in props validation                             react/prop-types
  14:46  error  'route' is missing in props validation                                  react/prop-types
  15:8   error  'ctx' is assigned a value but never used                                no-unused-vars
  18:4   error  'route.params.data' is missing in props validation                      react/prop-types
  18:4   error  'data' is assigned a value but never used                               no-unused-vars
  19:5   error  'route.params.address' is missing in props validation                   react/prop-types
  20:5   error  'route.params.phone' is missing in props validation                     react/prop-types
  21:5   error  'route.params.description' is missing in props validation               react/prop-types
  21:5   error  'description' is assigned a value but never used                        no-unused-vars
  22:5   error  'route.params.selectedDeliveryMode' is missing in props validation      react/prop-types
  23:12  error  'route.params' is missing in props validation                           react/prop-types
  27:14  error  'navigation.navigate' is missing in props validation                    react/prop-types
  45:28  error  'route.params.selectedDeliveryMode.key' is missing in props validation  react/prop-types

/Users/giladshemtov/pipelines/src/state/store.js
   1:10  error  'combineReducers' is defined but never used   no-unused-vars
  21:7   error  Unexpected lexical declaration in case block  no-case-declarations
  32:7   error  Unexpected lexical declaration in case block  no-case-declarations

/Users/giladshemtov/pipelines/src/util/util.js
  17:10  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token =

✖ 210 problems (210 errors, 0 warnings)
```

the script in my package.json is:

```
 "lint" :  "./node_modules/.bin/eslint '**/*.js' --fix/;exit 0"
```

thank you guys!

Answer (score 2):

problem solved! the image in the yml file was image: atlassian/default-image:2
and i changed it to image: node:14.15.1 and it works perfect now